# Plotting species distribution on map in R of Europe and Africa

Tags: r, maps, gbif

```
install.packages("rgbif")
library("rgbif")
```

```
Species.Name <- "The name of the species"
```

````
#Search GBIF and download observations
Species.key <- name_backbone(name=Species.Name)$speciesKey
locations <- occ_search(taxonKey=Species.key,hasCoordinate = TRUE, return='data', limit=20000)

#Remove localities with uncertain coordinates - meaning the observer entered approximate latitude and longitude data. This is common with very old specimens/records that were collected prior to handheld GPS devices being invented
locations <- subset(locations, coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <= 5000)
head(locations)

### **Create a Map**

#### Install the maps package to download the political boundaries for the region of interest so we can map out the data.
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
#install.packages("maps")
# Download Country Boundaries
world <- map_data("world")
````

Not sure how to get the entire scope of Europe and Africa show these localities on the map.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to create spatial object from `localities` occurence data. These data is table with columns `decimalLongitude` and `decimalLatitude`. You can use `sp` or `sf` package for this.

```
# make spatial point object from lat,lon columns
library(sp)
sp_occs <- SpatialPoints(coords = locations[c("decimalLongitude","decimalLatitude")],
                         proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))
```

You can use base `plot()` which is handy for quick data inspection.

```
# download world polygon data
library(maptools)
data("wrld_simpl")

# plot both spatial objects
plot(wrld_simpl)
plot(sp_occs,add=T,col="red")
```

[image]

To crop polygons to desired extent you can use `crop()` function from `raster` package. This will crop your polygon object by other spatial object or defined boundaries (extent).

```
library(raster)
extent_eur <- extent(-30,50,-30,70)

eur <- crop(wrld_simpl,extent_eur)

# plot cropped polygons and species points
plot(eur)
plot(sp_occs,
    pch=20,
    col="red",
    add=T)
```

[image]

Note that we cropped only world polygons, not the occurence data. If you need subset of the occurence data in that region, just use `crop()` in the same way. Also if you need map of specific countries you can also subset the polygon data by attributes (i.e. name/code of country or region if it is available)

Code example for *Mantis religiosa*:

```
library(rgbif)
library(raster)#loads also "sp" package
library(maptools)

Species.Name <- "mantis religiosa"

Species.key <- name_backbone(name=Species.Name)$speciesKey
locations <- occ_search(taxonKey=Species.key,hasCoordinate = TRUE, return='data', limit=500)
locations <- subset(locations, coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <= 5000)

sp_occs <- SpatialPoints(coords = locations[c("decimalLongitude","decimalLatitude")],
                         proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))

data("wrld_simpl")
extent_eur <- extent(-30,50,-30,70)

eur <- crop(wrld_simpl,extent_eur)

plot(eur)
plot(sp_occs,
    pch=20,
    col="red",
    add=T)
```